# Share script to multiple gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

I use GitLab CI.

I have a script used in the CI of multiple repository.

I want to use it without duplicating it in each repository, how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Project that contains all your shared/common scripts; you can then just use that project - eg. do a git clone in the `before_script` on that project and you can then use those shared/common scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multipipeline feature of Gitlab. Basically, create a repository with the pipeline and call it in another.

Here is the docs for it:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html

Comment: Does the job on the other repository use the environnement of the inital repository (I want to tag it) ?

Comment: You can pass variables from one to another.